# Why doesn't checkbox submit form value?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have several checkboxes in a form.  These are not server side checkboxes.  When any box is checked, it never comes across in the form post.  I'm using the following:

```
foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{...}
```

Any example checkbox is in this format:

```
<input id="chkFirstName" type="checkbox"/>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So you do not give the checkbox a name?

Comment: no - it does have an ID.

Comment: An `id` is not interchangable with `name`.  The latter is what makes it participate in `<form>` data semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `name` attribute. It is required to submit its value. The `id` attribute does *not* doe this.

```
<input id="chkFirstName" name="chkFirstName"  type="checkbox"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the `name=""` or `value=""` attributes on your `<input />` element. The `id` attribute is only used client-side, whereas the `name=""` attribute corresponds to the Request field set, finally an input element must have a value for it to be submitted too.

If you're using WebForms, then use ASP.NET Controls (either `<input runat="server" />` or `<asp:CheckBox />`) to take advantage of stronger-typing, validation, and other benefits.